# HP Pavilion Windows 8.1 Fn key + function key doesn't work in the System Startup to access BIOS

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, bios

**HP Pavilion Windows 8.1 Fn key + function key doesn't work in the System Startup to access BIOS.**

I can get to the system startup page but I cannot access the BIOS screen because the function keys on my HP Pavilion are not the primary function (ie volume, brightness etc.) So I have a Fn key to use but pressing Fn +F10 to access the BIOS screen doesn't work.

*Does anyone have a solution please?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to press the function key or FN Key. however I own an HP envy and F2 seems to work fine for me this link may help it looks like F10 should work for you

Comment: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00034791

Comment: I've tried pressing with and without the Fn key and it doesn't work, pressing enter to carry on with the boot is fun and the Function keys work once the laptop is fully booted it's just in the startup to try and access BIOS where I'm having issues.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use the FN key, just try F2 or F8

Comment: My bad just press F10 alone no FN key